# cast actionContext.ActionArguments to generic type - problems casting to generic type

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I’m writing a custom WebApi Authorization filter.

I need to read the `securitySqlConnectionString` back from the `actionContext` variable.  To do this, I need to perform a cast (e.g. as I have attempted using `TransactionRequestBundle<SearchDefault>`), however, the problem is that in `TransactionRequestBundle<T>`, `T` will vary, hence the cast below will only work for type `TransactionRequestBundle<SearchDefault>`.  As it turns out, I am not actually concerned with the information stored in `T`, so I would be happy to disregard the information stored in it.  I thought therefore that I might be able to get away with casting to `object` (as shown here), but this gives me a run-time cast error.

```
var securitySqlConnectionString =
  ((TransactionRequestBundle<object>)
  actionContext.ActionArguments["transactionRequestBundle"])
  .Transaction.SecuritySqlConnectionString;
```

So can anyone provide me with any guidance on what I need to do to get the line above to work correctly, specifically what do I replace `object` with?

```
public class XsycoApiAuthorizationFilter
   : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
      var securitySqlConnectionString =
        ((TransactionRequestBundle<object>)
          actionContext.ActionArguments["transactionRequestBundle"])
          .Transaction.SecuritySqlConnectionString;

      if (CacheMachine.GetEnvironments().Count == 0)
      {
        CacheLoader.Load(securitySqlConnectionString);
      }         
      base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}

public class TransactionRequestBundle<T>
{
    public Transaction Transaction;
    public T Model { get; set; }
    public XsycoDebugBundle XsycoDebugBundle { get; set; }

    public TransactionRequestBundle()
    {
        this.Transaction = new Transaction();
        this.XsycoDebugBundle = new XsycoDebugBundle();
        this.Model = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }

}

public class Transaction 
{
      public string SecuritySqlConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take an easier path to solve this problem.

You're trying to cast the object only for reading the `Transaction` field. What you can do is to create an interface like this:

```
public interface ITransaction
{
    public Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
}
```

Then implement it in your class

```
public class TransactionRequestBundle<object> : ITransaction
```

To implemente it simply convert the `Transaction` field into a `Transaction` property, like in the interface:

```
    public Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
```

And finally, instead of casting to `((TransactionRequestBundle<object>)` simply cast it to `(ITransaction)` which will give you access to that property.

Comment: That's great thanks JotaBe.  Your code worked for me with some minor tweaks: